# Kotlin, ArrayList set method doesn't replace the element with the given one

Tags: reference, kotlin

I'm porting [bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/) to [kotlin](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/bullet) and I wrote all the necessary stuff to run the HelloWorld sample.

I'm in debugging phase right now and I'm having problems with objects references.

At the very begin, I do enter `collideTTpersistentStack` a first time:

```
fun collideTTpersistentStack(root0: DbvtNode?, root1: DbvtNode?, collider: DbvtTreeCollider) {
    if (root0 != null && root1 != null) {
        var depth = 1
        var treshold = DOUBLE_STACKSIZE - 4

        val element = StkNN(root0, root1)
        if (stkStack.isNotEmpty()) stkStack[0] = element
        else stkStack += element
        stkStack resize DOUBLE_STACKSIZE
        do {
            val p = stkStack[--depth]
            if (depth > treshold) {
                stkStack resize (stkStack.size * 2)
                treshold = stkStack.size - 4
            }
            val pa = p.a!!
            val pb = p.b!!
            if (pa === pb) {
                if (pa.isInternal) {
                    stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pa.childs[0])
                    stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pa.childs[1])
                    stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pa.childs[1])
                }
            } else if (pa.volume intersect pb.volume)
                if (pa.isInternal)
                    if (pb.isInternal) {
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb.childs[0])
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb.childs[0])
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb.childs[1])
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb.childs[1])
                    } else {
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb)
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb)
                    }
                else
                    if (pb.isInternal) {
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa, pb.childs[0])
                        stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa, pb.childs[1])
                    } else
                        collider.process(pa, pb)
        } while (depth != 0)
    }
}
```

But since `root0` is `null` I'll quit right away. At the next time I enter the function, both `root0` and `root1` are valid objects, and their references are the following:

```
root0 = Dbvt@708
root1 = Dbvt@656
```

Then I create the first element to add to `stkStack`, that is still empty and is defined as:

```
val stkStack = ArrayList<StkNN>()
```

`element` is a `StkNN` Class so defined:

```
class StkNN(var a: DbvtNode? = null, var b: DbvtNode? = null)
```

After the insertion, I get:

[image]

Which makes sense.

`stkStack resize DOUBLE_STACKSIZE` simply create some dummy StkNN instances

Then I enter the `do` and I grab the first element on the `stkStack`, which is basically the element we just inserted:

```
p = {Dbvt$StkNN@731}
   a = {DbvtNode@708}
   b = {DbvtNode@656}
```

Then we skip the next `if`, I save the variables `p.a` and `p.b` as immutable checking against nullability

```
val pa = p.a!!
val pb = p.b!!
```

Both `pa` and `pb` are consistent in terms of references:

```
pa = @708
pb = @656
```

And now we land directly [here](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/bullet/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/bullet/collision/broadphaseCollision/Dbvt.kt#L417):

```
} else {
    stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb)
    stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb)
}
```

`depth` now is `0` and `stkStack` contains one element, the one we inserted at the begin, so it should replace it with a new instance

Well, `pa` childs are the following

```
pa = {DbvtNode@708} 
 childs = {DbvtNode[2]@748} 
  0 = {DbvtNode@759} 
  1 = {DbvtNode@656}
```

But after I jump over the assignments, `stkStack` will contain the following:

```
stkStack = {ArrayList@709}  size = 128
 0 = {Dbvt$StkNN@772} 
  a = {DbvtNode@708} // this is wrong, it should be @759
  b = {DbvtNode@656} 
 1 = {Dbvt$StkNN@781} 
  a = {DbvtNode@656} // right
  b = {DbvtNode@656} // right
```

C++ code uses pointers, and I double check the execution and its `stkStack[0].a` pointer is actually as it should be, that is, it corresponds to the `p.a->childs[0]` pointer

What is happening?

**Edit:** if I do create a dummy object before adding the instances:

```
val test = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb)
stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb)
stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb)
```

It does have the right reference, that is `test.a` is actually `pa.childs[0]`. If I assign `test` directly:

```
val test = StkNN(pa.childs[0], pb)
stkStack[depth++] = test
stkStack[depth++] = StkNN(pa.childs[1], pb)
```

`stkStack[0]` is **not** `test`..!
Looking at the docs in the `set(index: Int, element: Dbvt.stkNN)`, it says:

> Replace the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element

But this is not what happens

Comment: might be useful to debug it by wrapping the stkStack list with something that shows the get/set calls

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure, what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was something corrupted in my IDE/project ([related](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22639)). Re-cloning the project solved the problem

A special thanks to the downvote&run guys, it's always a pleasure